# create GTT, insert csv, using PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, csv

I have eight csv sheets, which where updated (every two hours) by an external service. I want to analyse these data - showing it in a php page for my boss....

I imagined, that it would be the easiest way to have the .csv in a GTT on my MsSQL Server. Maybe it is possible to create a GTT on ervery use (on commit preserve rows)? I still have no approach to make the csv to a normal format for insert syntax... is it even possible?

Or is there an other option? I try to catch some ideas for the solution...

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I have php code to read the .csv and put it into an array.

```
$csv_datei = "applicationData.csv";
$feler_trenner = ";";
$zeilen_trenner = "n";
if (@file_exists($csv_datei) == false) {
    echo 'Die CSV Datei: '. $csv_datei.' gibt es nicht!';
}

else {
    $datei_inhalt = @file_get_contents($csv_datei);
    $zeilen = explode($zeilen_trenner, $datei_inhalt);

    if (is_array($zeilen) == true) {
        foreach($zeilen as $zeile) {
           $felder = explode($feler_trenner, $zeile);
           $i = 0;
           if (is_array($felder) == true) {
                foreach($felder as $felde) {
                    if ($felde != '') {
                        echo (($i != 0) ? ', ':'') . str_replace('"', '', $felde);
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

source: [PHP-space.info](https://www.php-space.info/php-tutorials/41-csv,datei,einlesen,mit,php,und,ausgeben.html)

Comment: Have you got a begining of code...

Comment: @Meloman I updated my post